# Pandas filtering to get names of coaches who is coach for both men and women's team

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a dataframe like this -

```
    Name                        Country                     Discipline  Event
5   AIKMAN Siegfried Gottlieb   Japan                       Hockey      Men
6   AL SAADI Kais               Germany                     Hockey      Men
8   ALEKNO Vladimir             Islamic Republic of Iran    Volleyball  Men
9   ALEKSEEV Alexey             ROC                         Handball    Women
11  ALSHEHRI Saad               Saudi Arabia                Football    Men
.
.
.
```

I want to get the `Name`s (Name of coaches) who is coach for both Men and Women team of a particular game(Discipline)

Please help me with this

Comment: In your example, none are doing both :) Have you tried something yet? We're here to help, no to do your work ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and check for groups that have `Event` count >= 2:

```
filtered = df.groupby(['Discipline', 'Name']).filter(lambda x: x['Event'].count() >= 2)
```

If you want a list of unique names, then simply:

```
>>> filtered.Name.unique()
```